# How to create the below table (multiple group with t-test) in R?

Tags: r, panel

Here the descriptive data in a research article; how to create this in one go in R?
[image: Table to be made]

Comment: The `gt` package should be able to do it, but you would have to construct your table with it quite carefully, of course. Link: https://gt.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks, mate... Do you know how to run industry * time-fixed effects in a regression?

Comment: You are welcome! Regarding regression: generally yes... but that seems to be an entirely new question. If you have a "troubled model" that doesn't work the way you want you might want to ask it as a new SO-question. Make sure you have read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. There are plenty of amazing experts around here...